# Django Chart.js

Tags: django, chart.js

I am trying to setup Chart.js to use in my project.
This is [example](https://github.com/peopledoc/django-chartjs) with i am trying to reproduce and i get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Bak7.png)
I am using PyCharm, so it was easy to download all libraries and i added chart.js in Installed aps

My test.html:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
    <head>
        <title>django-chartjs line chart demo</title>
        <!--[if lte IE 8]>
            <script src="{% static 'js/excanvas.js' %}"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Some Line Charts loaded in Ajax!</h1>

        <canvas id="myChart" width="500" height="400"></canvas>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/Chart.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $.get('{% url "line_chart_json" %}', function(data) {
                var ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
                new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'line', data: data
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My view:

```
   class LineChartJSONView(BaseLineChartView):
        def get_labels(self):
            """Return 7 labels for the x-axis."""
            return ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"]

        def get_providers(self):
            """Return names of datasets."""
            return ["Central", "Eastside", "Westside"]

        def get_data(self):
            """Return 3 datasets to plot."""

            return [[75, 44, 92, 11, 44, 95, 35],
                    [41, 92, 18, 3, 73, 87, 92],
                    [87, 21, 94, 3, 90, 13, 65]]
    line_chart = TemplateView.as_view(template_name='main/mark/test.html')
    line_chart_json = LineChartJSONView.as_view()
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're looking at the json result; you're doing something like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/yourapp/line_chart/json
```

where you should do:

```
http://localhost:8000/yourapp/line_chart
```